# How to match all strings that has only one dot using regular expression

Tags: regex, validation

I need to capture strings containing only one dot. String will mostly contains domain names like

test.com, fun.test.com, lesh.test.com.

I need to check only the first one and to ignore the string that has more than one dots.

How can I do this using regex?

Comment: Negating the match is faster i.e. No match `\..*\.` and string is ok.

Comment: What if the string contains no dots?

Comment: For must contain a dot, use a string method to see if it contains a dot first, then validate no dup dots by negating the match i.e. no match `\..*\.` and string is ok.

Comment: The speed difference can be seen by given an equal sample of 2 passes and 2 fails out of 4 total `asssssssf.asssssssf \n assss.sssf.asssssssf \n asssssssf.asssssssf \n assss.sssf.asssssssf` the speed difference : `Regex1:   \..*\.
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.20 s,   202.78 ms,   202778 µs
Matches per sec:   493,150
Regex2:   ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.37 s,   373.61 ms,   373605 µs
Matches per sec:   267,662`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

Check explanations https://regex101.com/r/mn7Ccr/1